# Since iOS 14, my app does not display images only when with the debugger or a device with iOS 13. Also, the keyboard won't show all keys

Tags: swift, keyboard, ios13, ios14, xcode12

So I have an app works great in iOS 13, but since the release of iOS 14 I have this issue with the app. It shows the keyboard when using an inputs but some or most of the keys are not displayed -- you can still write with it, but you don't actually know which letter you are typing.

Also, images don't display either. In iOS 13 this works fine, in my app also when I run the app and attach to Xcode it also works fine. However, if I make a build, try and detach the app from Xcode 12, or make an archive, images won't display or take a template color of white. I think they just don't appear.

Anyone have face this problem yet?

Comment: Hey before giving a down vote at lease please tell me what is unclear "The problem: Images and key board on my app are not displaying since Apple iOS 14 and Xcode 12 release for devices with the IOS 14 unless im running it attached or from Xcode and connected to Xcode". iOS 13 the runs fine

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? i am facing the same issue

Comment: @joelalcantara, please highlight the question correctly. Also, example code would be nice if you are really looking for someone to spend some time to answer.

Comment: Please re-write your question using linebreaks, bullet points, and `code` where needed. It's currently VERY difficult to read. It should also be limited to a single specific question.

Comment: I made an edit, but the question still sounds like it's asking 2 different things...

Comment: @manishg sorry about the question I'm new asking questions here but post an answer that not yet the problem solution but you can identify that the problem is the Gifu library right now ill try and install a previous version because there is no fix yet they are working on it I left the link to the GitHub discussion in my answer (basically there is something messing with the animations of the **Gifu** library so I think we will have to wait for them to fix it mean while ill try to test with previous versions)

Answer (score 1):

So I found out that the problem is de Gifu pod thanks to @Raffista comment I could identify it I found that they are discussing this matter actually there is not yet a solution in this link there is the GitHub issue [link](https://github.com/kaishin/Gifu/issues/167)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faces this issue with not having Gifu pod ( I don't have Gifu pod but still face this issue), you can go through the below temporary solution.

I haven't found a permanent solution to this but could figure out a temporary one. I found that all my older app version on TestFlight didn't had this issue where image / keyboard keys were not visible even on IOS 14. Made me think maybe the issue isn't with iOS 14 , the issue very well resides with build creation in Xcode 12. I downgraded my Xcode from 12 to 11.7 and tried to replicate the issue and voila it worked. Although i agree this is not an actual solution , but for people out there who need to make an urgent release you can try this. Meanwhile i still await / searching for the solution for Xcode 12.

To downgrade Xcode , simply delete Xcode from application folder and download Xcode 11.7 from the below link.

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=xcode

If anyone finds an actual solution for XCode 12 please do post it here.